# What is CKM_SSL3_SHA1_MAC in PKCS 11 ? (difference between CKM_SHA_1_HMAC and CKM_SSL3_SHA1_MAC )

Tags: sha1, sign, pkcs#11

I'm trying  to implement some function of PKCS 11 standard , In Sign functions group, When you call SignInit you send the mechanism type , I have conflict between two mechanisms:

1- CKM_SHA_1_HMAC: it is a sha1 with HMAC (use key) and the output is 20 byte long.

2- CKM_SSL3_SHA1_MAC : which i can't know what algorithm it use or how to implement it(by using openssl or polarssl) ?

Answer (score 1):

`CKM_SSL3_SHA1_MAC` and `CKM_SSL3_MD5_MAC` are not HMAC.
They are defined in SSL3.0 standard(RFC 6101).

You can find the algorithm in this [document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#page-17).

Because `CKM_SSL3_SHA1_MAC` is part of SSL3.0 standard, both openssl and polarssl already implement it.